# Loading CSS before Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance

I have designed custom navbar/menu. It currently calls CSS from my style.css and the JS which is used is included in the PHP file using the following setup

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
 <nav> ... </nav>
 <script>
$(function () {
        $('.toggle-menu').click(function (){
        $('.exo-menu').toggleClass('display');

        });
    });
    jQuery(document).ready( function ( $ ){
        $(".change>a").hover( function () { 
            $(this)[0].click();
        }, 
        function () {
        /* code for mouseout */
    });
    });
</script>
```

The internal JS seems to be causing a problem with the CSS loading.

Is there any way I can load the called CSS before the JS whilst keeping it as is, without putting the Javascript on a seperate .js sheet?

So far  have tried:

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body onload="initNavigation()">
    <nav> ... </nav>
    <script>
        function initNavigation() {
            $(function () {
                $('.toggle-menu').click(function (){
                $('.exo-menu').toggleClass('display');
                });
            });
            jQuery(document).ready( function ( $ ){
                $(".change>a").hover( function () { 
                $(this)[0].click();
                }, 
                function () {
                /* code for mouseout */
                });
            });
        }
    </script>
</body/>
```

and

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav> ... </nav>
    <script>
        window.onload=function(){
            $(function () {
                $('.toggle-menu').click(function (){
                $('.exo-menu').toggleClass('display');
                });
            });
            jQuery(document).ready( function ( $ ){
                $(".change>a").hover( function () { 
                $(this)[0].click();
                }, 
                function () {
                /* code for mouseout */
                });
            });
        }
    </script>
</body/>
```

Can anyone tell me where I have went wrong? i am thinking its the .ready part but if it is, not sure how to get rid of it without affecting how the JS works?

Might it make a difference if I moved the JS to the head and placed it below the CSS?

Comment: Why do you think the internal JS is causing a problem with the CSS loading? What kind of problem?

Comment: Put the javascript just before the ending body tag.

Comment: @Znaneswar your suggestion requires jQuery, but OP probably uses plain JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the onload event in your body tag and wrap your js in a function.

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body onload="initNavigation()">

  <nav></nav>

  <script>
    function initNavigation() {
      // your script goes here
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I have tried this, and the options above. none seem to work.I am at a total loss,have no clue what else to try :-( lol

Comment: I have included the exact JS used in the question above

Comment: In fact that you are using jQuery $(document).ready() should exactly do what you want. If not the problem may caused by something different. https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Did you have any errors in your console or are you able to create a fiddle?

Comment: So as it is currently set up i should not need to use any sort of onload?.. I have no clue what is happening then. first time I load the site after clearing cache the menu displays all broken up as a list with bullet points, with no container. after refresh the menu is as it should be... Could it make a difference if I move the JS from the body to the head under the called CSS?

Comment: sounds like you don't have any js problems. You better should provide a link to you little project.

Comment: I appologise. Your answer did work... the reason it wasnt was because I had 2 similar plugins trying to do the same job - WP Fastest Cache and JS & CSS Script Optimizer that seemed to be conflicting. Thanks again... Im new to this lol. prone to a daft mistake, massive learning curve.